# Unordered list nested in an ordered list

Tags: html, nested-lists

I've nested an unorderdered list in an ordered list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Cascaded lists</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- First level -->
  <ol>List1
    <li>List1 item1</li>
    <li>List1 item2</li>
    
      <!-- Second level -->
      <ul>List2
        <li>List2 item1</li>
        <li>List2 item2</li>
        <li>List2 item3</li>
      </ul>
    <li>List1 item3</li>
    <li>List1 item4</li>   
  </ol>

</body>

</html>
```

But in Google Crome, Windows Explorer and Firefox I get different results of the list entries counter.

With Google Crome and Windows Explorer it works fine:

```
List1 
1.List1 item1
2.List1 item2
 List2 
◦List2 item1
◦List2 item2
◦List2 item3
3.List1 item3
4.List1 item4
```

But with Firefox this doesn't work and the items counter doesn't ignore the items of the unordered list and this looks like this:

```
List1 
1.List1 item1
2.List1 item2
 List2 
◦List2 item1
◦List2 item2
◦List2 item3
4.List1 item3
5.List1 item4
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Your embedded list needs to be inside the `<li>` element that contains it. Currently it is inserted between two list elements.

So instead of:

```
<li>List1 item2</li>

  <!-- Second level -->
  <ul>List2
    <li>List2 item1</li>
    <li>List2 item2</li>
    <li>List2 item3</li>
  </ul>
```

You should have:

```
<li>List1 item2 <!-- removed /li from here -->

  <!-- Second level -->
  <ul>List2
    <li>List2 item1</li>
    <li>List2 item2</li>
    <li>List2 item3</li>
  </ul>
</li> <!-- added /li here -->
```

Here is a fiddle showing this structure, and it works correctly in both Chrome, Firefox, and Edge: https://jsfiddle.net/dnyrs940/